# GWT Compiler: Adding two numbers is creating a string

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I have this code, goal being, take some numbers, and give me another number. Easy enough.

```
private final int height = 5;

private double interpolateDoubleProperty(
    int heightAtLower, int heightAtHigher,      //4, 10
    double lowValue, double highValue)          //1, 0
{        
    double lowToHighDelta = heightAtHigher - heightAtLower;          // 6 = 10 - 4        
    double lowToThisDelta = (double)this.height    - heightAtLower;  // 1 = 5 - 4        
    double lerpRatio = lowToThisDelta / lowToHighDelta;              // 0.17  = 1 / 6        
    double valueDelta = highValue - lowValue;                        // -1 = 0 - 1
    double increment = lerpRatio * valueDelta;                       // -0.17 = 0.17 * -1
    double toReturn = lowValue + increment;                          // 0.83 = 1 + -0.17

    GWT.log("interpolated value = " + toReturn);

    return toReturn;
}
```

However, the returned value I'm getting is bad. For this case (see comments for input values) the GWT log output is:

**interpolated value = 1-0.16666666666666666**

Which tells me that "toReturn" is getting treated like a string, it's value being equal to the concatenation of "lowValue" and "increment".

This is GWT, so whatever Java code I'm writing here is getting compiled into JS, and at some point the value is getting mistakenly cast into a string. What could be causing this? Anyway to resolve it? I'm using GWT v2.6.

Bear with the naming, lowValue and highValue and indeed supposed to be 1 and 0 respectively.

Comment: Are you calling `interpolateDoubleProperty` from JS directly? (i.e. calling from native JS as opposed to GWT-compiled JS).

Comment: I do not see this behaviour with GWT 2.8.0.  `interpolated value = 0.8333333333333334`.  Can you try updating?  Also, try compiling with the full pretty version of the output, you can see what JS has been produced and maybe understand what's going on that way.

Comment: I am calling interpolateDoubleProperty only from GWT-compiled JS

Comment: Updating is not an option in the short term (big project with a team). Will look at the pretty output.

Comment: I've just had a go with GWT2.6.0 and i still don't see the issue, i'm afraid.  Try and trace the JS in your browser's debugger, see what it's up to.

Comment: Novice question, where would I find the output after pretty compilation?

Comment: Look at the Network tab in your browser debugging tools. Look for the JS that is named with hexa chars (dot js).

Comment: Do you have GWT Super Dev Mode set up? It's easier to use than browser debuggers.

Comment: I recommend to calculate with BigDecimal, you get no problems with decimal points and I think it can fix your problem

Answer (score 2):

Solved it:

The variable **lowValue** was originally coming from a field that was being set by an HTML slider created and managed with JSNI code:

```
private static native double getSliderValue(String sliderID) /*-{
    return $doc.getElementById(sliderID).value;       
}-*/;
```

After compilation, there's no guarentee that the slider's value was actually a double (it was actually saved as a string!). It eventually made it's way into the **interpolateDoubleProperty** input parameter and broke any variable that it got added to.

To fix this, we just needed to "sanitize" the value field a bit by multiplying by **1.0**.

```
private static native double getSliderValue(String sliderID) /*-{
    return $doc.getElementById(sliderID).value * 1.0;
}-*/;
```

This code helped me tracked down what type a variable actually was at runtime after compilation, eventually leading me back to the slider.

```
GWT.log("Value: '" + variableToTest + "' is actually type: '" + ((Object)variableToTest).getClass().getName() + "'");
```